# "The selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server" ERROR

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web, dynamic

So, I have imported this team project from Github and set up a Tomcat. I start Tomcat through the eclipse and try to run our main file "login.jsp" on a server, as shown on
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAewT.jpg).

But every time I try to run it, I receive this error - "The selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server". [screenshot of an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMl9u.jpg)
I have tried dozens of solution from going to the Project Facets and  swapping for the Dynamic Web to, basically, changing something inside the files but nothing seems to work.

P.S. There is an actual working code in "login.jsp" . It seems to works on my friend's PC, but not on mine.

Comment: what did you deploy on tomcat?

Comment: @Stultuske it's a program with mySQL database that we try to integrate to the web from a standart desktop application.

Comment: no: what? .class files? an ear? a war? or how did you try to run something?

Answer (score 1):

Note sure, how your code reaches the main method.

There could be a number of reasons why it isn't working, here are some things to consider in troubleshooting:

1. First thing to validate is whether or not Tomcat has been installed correctly and is running without errors. You say you installed a Tomcat plugin for Eclipse. I didn't know there was one. I usually install Tomcat separately and then configure Tomcat settings in Eclipse. Or did you install Tomcat via the Servers view? Windows -> View -> Other -> Server -> Servers, right click in Server view and go New -> Server. Select Apache and then Tomcat?
2. Can you start and stop Tomcat within Eclipse? If so can you open a browser and navigate to http://localhost:8080 - a Tomcat console should display. Check the logs there shouldn't be any errors.
3. You should be able to right click on your web project and say run on server and select Tomcat. Alternatively in the Server view right click on the Tomcat server and select Add and Remove.
4. If the 3rd step didn't work it is possible that the imported project has errors. Could be referencing Libraries that don't exist or paths that are invalid. Open the problems view and see if there are any compile errors. Open the errors view and see if there are any eclipse errors. Right click the project -> Build path -> Configure build path. Examine the reference libraries and see if there are any errors or warnings.
5. If you the above all works and you have still not made any progress try creating a simple dynamic web application from scratch and run that on the server.

Comment: 1. yes, I have done both, installed a plugin and added tomcat to the servers. 2. yes, I can start, but when I start tomcat from the command prompt I am getting a different picture to the one when I start tomcat from the eclipse. If ran in the command prompt I am getting a normal tomcat page with their links and stuff, but if ran by the eclipse I am getting "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found" page with the description that says  - "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: 3. Yep, I can do that but still getting HTTP Status 404 - Not found page. 4. No, no errors found, and the libraries are all ok. 5. I believe it's somehow connected to this HTTP Status 404 page. I dont know why but when tomcat is run by the command prompt everything seem to display properly. Anyways, thanks for your time and effort!